# How to set packet arrival rate and send interval as separate parameters

Tags: omnet++, inet

In OMNeT++/INET, under sensornetwork/omnetpp.ini, the following code is given where packet arrival rate and the rate at which packets are transmitted to the server are considered as same parameter (`sendInterval`).

```
*.sensor*.app[0].sendInterval = 1s
*.sensor*.app[0].startTime = exponential(1s)
*.sensor*.app[0].messageLength = 10Byte
```

But, i need to set the following:

- Random packet arrival rate for each node.
- Poisson packet arrival rate and the rate at which packets are transmitted to the server are two separate parameters.

Would anyone please suggest?

Comment: Could you clarify "rate at which packets are transmitted to the server are two separate parameters"?

Comment: @Jerzy, with this scenario, the sensors send 50 packets each during the 50s. So, for four nodes 200 packets are sent in total. By saying the rate at which packets are transmitted to the server, i meant for each node how many packet is transmitted per second.

Comment: To control total number of packets you may use for example `UdpBasicApp` and set startTime=0s, stopTime=50s and sendInterval=1s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One cannot control directly *arrival* rate, only *sending* rate may be controlled. The arrival rate depends on many factors (e.g. load of links, other traffic in nodes, route selection etc.).
To set a random sending rate write for example:

```
*.sensor*.app[0].sendInterval = uniform(0.5s, 1.5s)
```

The available random distributions are listed in [OMNeT++ Simulation Manual, Chapter 7.4](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:sim-lib:random-variate-generation).

Comment: Jerzy, by setting a random sending rate, I can only control how many packets are transmitted/sent to the server per second, is not it?

Comment: For this single-hop scenario, there is no routing implemented. Here, UDP datagrams are generated and sent at fixed rate defined by sendInterval. I want packet generation rate will be different than packet sent rate. For example, 4 packets are generated per second and stored in the queue and 2 packets are transmitted per second. The goal is to model  a scenario where a sender will have more packets (random) in its queue after sending its first packet. Would you please suggest how i can do that?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use a queue. In OMNet++ there is ready to use [cQueue class](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:sim-lib:cqueue). You should prepare own UDP application. However, you should be aware that for your example every second two packets are added to the queue, so after some time queue will overflow (usually every queue has some capacity).

Comment: Jerzy, i read cQueue class, however i could not figure out where i can use that to model my scenario that i mentioned above. Would you please give me an example using code? To avoid overflowing, i was thinking to have infinite capacity. Thank you

Comment: Your scenario required a non-standard model, so you should prepare a new UDP application. In short: create application similar to UdpBasicApp, prepare parameters to control your behavior (e.g. generateInterval, sendInterval etc.), add an instance of cQueue, add two or more self-messages. Look how UdpBasicApp works and try to prepare a new application by yourself.

Comment: Jerzy, to prepare a new UDP application, do i need to write .cc and .ned file under udpapp folder? Thank you

Comment: Yes, you should create at least .ned, .cc and .h.

Comment: Jerzy, would you please give me an example how to add an instance of cQueue in UdpBasicApp?

Comment: In `UdpBasicApp.h` write `cQueue queue;` under `protected` area.

Comment: Jerzy, I meant UdpBasicApp.cc file. How I can store the packets in the queue after generating it? Thank you

Comment: I suggest adding a new question with the code you have prepared and description of your problem or error.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I wil post a new question. Before that, can you suggest me what you meant by "add two or more self-messages"? I meant self-massages for which purpose?

Comment: In OMNeT++ a selfmessage is used to generate some action in particular time. You have mentioned that you want to control process of generating packets as well as process of sending packets. Therefore, you need a selfmessage to involve generating of a packet, and another selfmessage to involve sending packet.

Comment: Jerzy, to set random packet generation rate, will the same ```uniform``` command work?

Comment: Yes. Uniform (a, b) returns a random number from the range (a, b).